# Filling input field with expression language issue

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, expression, el

I have problem with filling input field with request attribute using expression language. It's work correct when i display this attribute using for example `${title}`but when I trying fill input by this way `<input name="bookTitle" type="text" value=${title} >` it only fill one first word. What I doing wrong?
My code below:

editBook.jsp

```
<tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td><input name="bookTitle" type="text" 
                            value=${title} ></td>
                    </tr>
```

adminPanel.jsp

`<a href="editBookServlet?bookTitle=${book.title}">Edit</a>`

editBookServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String title = request.getParameter("bookTitle");
request.setAttribute("title", title);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/editBook.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap `value=${title}` in the quotes like this:
`value="${title}"`